# COS method option pricing

Tags: option-pricing, exotics, barrier

is the cos method used to calculate prices of options other than the European call? Or is this method only used for calibration? Is it possible to evaluate the barrier and lookback options? I am asking from the point of view of practice

Comment: This [follow-up paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-009-0252-4) by Fang and Oosterlee (2009) discusses the pricing of American options and discrete barrier options. [This paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/110853339?mobileUi=0&) by Zhang and Oosterlee (2013) discusses the ASCOS method (COS method for Asian options) which is generalised to early exercise features [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168927413001621). I guess you can apply similar ideas to lookback options. By the way, Fang Fang and Bowen Zhang were Oosterlee's PhD students.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to read it. Do you recommend any book for learning theory about Fourier series and fourier transform?

Comment: You don't need a book on Fourier transforms or Fourier series. The summary from [Schmelzle](https://pfadintegral.com/docs/Schmelzle2010%20Fourier%20Pricing.pdf) includes all the properties of characteristic functions you need to understand what's going on. But if you want to, [Hirsa (2013)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Computational-Methods-Finance-Financial-Mathematics/dp/1439829578) covers the plain COS method and it's very accessible. He also addresses early exercise and barrier options but no Asian or lookback options. It's a great pick if you're into numerics.

Comment: @KeSchn But I would like to understand why we can write a function $f:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ as a cosine series expansion. Why we have equality? I heard that only periodic functions can be written in this form

Comment: Okay, well that's a well-known fact and proven in most standard (functional) analysis books. It doesn't hold for all functions. You best start with $L^2$ and show that $\sin$ and $\cos$ form a basis of this space (I guess it's more effort to do it for all $L^1$ functions) Then, you immediately get the Fourier series. But anyways, you won't struggle to find this result in any introductory book on higher analysis.

Comment: Can you only explain me equations $27$ and $28$ from http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/mf/users/oosterlee/oosterlee/COS.pdf ? Because I don't understand why we have relation like this for Levy process. Since $x$ is a stock price at time $t_0$, why there is $x=0$

Comment: @KeSchn is there a mistake in Fang and Osterlee 2010 in table 1.2? In Kou model in $\xi_2$ shouldn't be $-\frac{\lambda (1-p)}{\eta_2^2}$? Do you check this cumulant? Or do you know a paper where there is a list of cumulant for different LEvy processes not only for this in Fang Osterlee?

Comment: I haven't checked this cumulant but you can simply use the characteristic function of the Kou model to compute the cumulant. This way you can verify whether you're right. Please add a comment here if you find them to be wrong, I'd be interested to know! :) Regarding your previous question, I think to remember that $x=\ln\left(\frac{S_0}{K}\right)$. Thus $x=0$ means $S_0=K$. But I would have to check the paper again.

Comment: @KeSchn I checked only cumulants for Kou and Merton model and I found 2 errors: In Kou model $c_2$ should be equal $t\left(\sigma^2+2\frac{\lambda p}{\eta_1^2}-2\frac{\lambda(1-p)}{\eta_2^2}\right)$ and in Merton model $c_4$ should be equal $t\lambda(\mu^4+6\delta^2\mu^2+3\delta^4)$ (I use different notation).

Comment: That's cool to know. Thanks for the info! I may check it soon myself. If you're sure about your findings, you may want to email Fang or Oosterlee. Kienitz and Wetterau (2013, Table 5.2) also state cumulants for GBM, Merton, Heston, NIG, VG and CGMY models. The book is called ``Financial Modelling''.

Comment: I take characteristic function of $\ln(S_t/S_0)$ and calculate IT value at point $-iu$ to get moment generating function. Fang and osterlee write cumulants for $\ln(S_t/K)$.

Comment: So, do you get the same results as Fang & Oosterlee if you use the same method as they do?

Comment: @math122, could you please let me know if I can have access to the coded implementation of COS method for the American options? I've read the article by Fang and Oosterlee. I would be very thankful if you could help me with this.